# Force Batch execution directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch that is started by drag&droping a file ontop of it (aka %1 argument = file path). But that causes it to start in the directory the dropped file is located in.

Q: How do i force the batch to run in the directory the .bat file is located in (paths may change so it can't be static). Is there some way of obtaining the directory of the .bat file and then move via cd command to the directory before executing any more lines?

Comment: Make the first line of your batch file `@CD /D "%~dp0"`, then just create the rest of your script as necessary below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory of your **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** is: **`"%~dp0"`**

The directory of dropped file is: **`"%~dp1"`**

```cmd
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0"

echo/ & echo/ Bat path is: "%~dp0"
echo/ & echo/ Current path is: "%__CD__%" or "%CD%"
echo/ & echo/ Argument path is: "%~dp1"

%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1
```

---

**Obs.:**

***aka %1 argument = file path***  Is not quite true, this is your argument, for path you need use **`"%~dp1"`**

- **[Syntax Args](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)**

  - How-to: Pass Command Line arguments (Parameters) to a Windows batch file.